# less - force variable to compile before adding it to the "calc()" function

Tags: css, less

My Question: is there a way to force the less compiler to pre-calc the math of specific variables

My Problem:
(simplified example - please ignore the usefullness of the code)

first try:

```
@font-size-min: 16px;
@font-size-max: 18px;

body {
    font-size: calc((100vw - @font-size-min) / (@font-size-max - @font-size-min));
}


//result (compiled css):
font-size: calc((100vw - 16px) / (18px - 16px));
```

This css throws an error which i dont really understand, but the brackets after the divider state: "invalid value".
I have tested it in Chrome and Firefox so far.

second try:

```
@font-size-min: 16px;
@font-size-max: 18px;
@font-size-diff: (@font-size-max - @font-size-min); //should be 2

body {
    font-size: calc((100vw - @font-size-min) / @font-size-diff);    //removed the brackets to avoid the error
}


//result (compiled css):
font-size: calc((100vw - 16px) / (18px - 16px));
```

O.o waiiit a second, that didnt do anything.
So now iam here to find your help^^.

Is there a way for force "@font-size-diff" to precompile before passing on its value?

Iam solving this problem atm with handwriting the calculated value which is very time consuming.

Thank you all for your time and have a nice Day.

Comment: you cannot divide by a unit, read the doc of calc --> `Division. The right-hand side must be a <number>`

Comment: And the Less version is 3.x? If so this is expected output (Less no longer tries t evaluate *anything* within `calc` statements - it may result in inefficient CSS result but the way (like it was in 2.x and eralier) is even worse)).

Comment: (In details: `@font-size-diff` (and any variable) is not evaluated until it's actually used for some CSS property and when the expression is `calc`, the variable value is forced to be kept *as is*.) There's a hack though (I'm not sure if it could fit your particular case) variables passed as args to mixins are always evaluated - thus something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/a0348ed8a6fbe09e72e4abae37e74d28) should do the trick.

Comment: @ TemaniAfif - thank you, since i was searching all over less i forgot to check the calc doc - blind me
@seven-phases-max - iam using the newest versions of everythig atm.
I will try out this trick - thank you very much

You guys are awesome - i didnt expect answers this fast wow :D

Comment: ive played around a bit and found a stupidly simple solution.. :
@font-size-diff: abs(@font-size-max - @font-size-min);

Comment: `abs(@font-size-max - @font-size-min);` that does the trick too (and it's even more simple than what I suggested above). Note however that what @TemaniAfif noted ("no unit for the divider") still applies so something like [`unit(@font-size-max - @font-size-min)`](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40a%3A%2016px%3B%5Cn%40b%3A%2018px%3B%5Cn%40c%3A%20unit(%40a%20-%20%40b)%3B%5Cn%5Cnfoo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20calc(whatever%20%2F%20%40c)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D) would fit even better. Just `abs` won't remove a unit from the result.